# I can't sort a matrix in my way

Tags: java, sorting, matrix

I want to sort a Matrix 'for example 6 rows x 6 columns', exactly like this:

```
0 | 15 | 0 | 06 | 0 | 04
1 | 19 | 1 | 99 | 1 | 86
2 | 55 | 2 | 54 | 2 | 12
3 | 82 | 3 | 73 | 3 | 23
4 | 66 | 4 | 95 | 4 | 11
5 | 43 | 5 | 93 | 5 | 13
```

We see that the 1st & 3rd & 5th columns are the same. That's what I need. I was trying to sort the 2nd & 4th & 6th columns *in descending way* to get this result:

```
3 | 82 | 1 | 99 | 1 | 86
4 | 66 | 4 | 95 | 3 | 23
2 | 55 | 5 | 93 | 5 | 13
5 | 43 | 3 | 73 | 2 | 12
1 | 19 | 2 | 54 | 4 | 11
0 | 15 | 0 | 06 | 0 | 04
```

When I move the maximum of the 2nd column, I also move his number *or his name in the 1st column*, for example, we move `(3:82)` to the first place then `(4:66)` and `(2:55)` and so on, the same work to the other columns.

I was trying and searching to solve this problem, I found *sorting matrix with Table header clicking* but in this case, we sort only one column. I want to sort 3. In addition to this, the second thing that I don't want is *sorting using table header clicking (you must click on the table header to sort the values)*. I want to do it automatically without clicking.

That's what I used in my little code:

```
    Table2.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(Table2.getPreferredSize());
    Table2.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)Table2.getRowSorter());
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add( new RowSorter.SortKey(2, SortOrder.DESCENDING) );
    sorter.setSortKeys(list);
    sorter.sort();

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( Table2 );
    getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

So I am trying to think of other ways to do this without using `JTable` and the `getRowSorter` option.

Comment: you should add the programming language in the tags.

Comment: I think there is no way to do this with built-in functionality. You will have to save your matrix in an array (or list) and sort it. Then you can show the matrix however you want (for instance with a `JTable` and your own `TableModel`). Whenever something changes in the table, you have to resort the array and update the table.

Comment: correction: maybe there i a way with row sorters like you tried. I would be very interested in such a solution as well.

Comment: Thank you Mr. brimborium